# Google App Script: Trying to setFormula for Spreadsheet cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to set the formula for a Google Spreadsheet cell using the `cell.setFormula` function.

This is my code from the function. The line of code of importance is the last one where I try to `setFormula`.

```
//Create new empty project sheet
function copySheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var temp = ss.getSheetByName("Project_Template");
  var name = Browser.inputBox("Create New Project", "Enter name for new project", Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
  if (name != "cancel") {
    ss.insertSheet(name,1, {template:temp})
    //Add project name to project code cell
    var newSheet = ss.getSheetByName(name);
    var cell = newSheet.getRange(3, 2);
    cell.setValue(name);
    //Update formula in placemarkers sheet
    var rowNum = ss.getNumSheets() - 3;
    var formulaSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Placemarkers");
    var formulaCell = formulaSheet.getRange(rowNum, 1);
    formulaCell.setFormula('=if(isna(filter('name'!AH3:AH3,'name'!AH3:AH3 <> ""))=true,"",filter('name'!AH3:AH3,'name'!AH3:AH3 <> ""))');
  }
}
```

When I try to save the script, I get the following error message:

```
Missing ) after argument list. (line 103)
```

I am sure it has to do with the combination of quotation and double quotation marks. I have not been able to get it working without an error message. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `+` operator is not inserted to join string and the `name` variable. The following code part fixes the problem

```
formulaCell.setFormula('=if(isna(filter(' + name + '!AH3:AH3,' + name + '!AH3:AH3 <> ""))=true,"",filter(' + name + '!AH3:AH3,' + name + '!AH3:AH3 <> ""))');
```

Comment: Yes, found the problem myself just as you posted this. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

.. it is not working to me.

```
cell.setFormula("=COUNTIF('name'!B14:B71,"G:*")");
cell.setFormula("=COUNTIF(' + name + '!B14:B71,"G:*")");
```

I guess that problem is with **"** in the **setFormula's** input.

It takes the **"** in the content of formula as a terminator of its parameter field and awaits **)** symbol to enclose method call.

Solution:

Insert \ before **"** in the **setFormula** string:

```
cell.setFormula("=COUNTIF('name'!B14:B71,\"G:*\")");
```

_