# Using column header variables in R1C1 formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**I am attempting to:**

1. Have google script perform a function that inserts formulas (I think using R1C1) into Column G in this example based on column F, and using variables for the column reference in the formula. The Formula is =NETWORKDAYS. **I want to ensure my function searches for the column header names instead of the number in case the columns are moved.**
2. The formula inserted into column G would change changed which column its pulling from, depending on column F
3. For our example here, if Yes in Column F, Column G would have the formula =NETWORKDAYS(A2,D2) with this being input to each cell respectively in column G.

If no, the formula would be =NETWORKDAYS(A2,B2), with the formula inserted into each cell respectively in column G.

**Current Issue:**

1. I am unsure how to code this so that the formula uses the column header name instead of a hard-coded column number reference like you would do in R1C1 notation
2. I am not great with IF statements, and "passing through" items in a range (i.e. making the function move through the range), this is still a grey area for me

***Current Sheet:***
[image: 1]

***What I would like to have happen/End Result of script:***
[image: 2]

**Yes Formula Example**
[image: 3]

**No Formula Example**
[image: 4]

***Current Code:***

```js
function trainingDays(){

  //const/variables to find Training Days column
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheet1');
  const tf = ws.createTextFinder('Training Days');
  tf.matchEntireCell(true).matchCase(false);//finds text "Training Days" exactly
  const regionCellCol = tf.findNext().getColumn()//finds first instance of training days
  const regionCellRow = tf.findNext().getRow()

  //const/variables to find Race Date Announced
  const tfRaceDateAnnounced = ws.createTextFinder('Race Date Announced');
  tfRaceDateAnnounced.matchEntireCell(true).matchCase(false);//finds text "Race Date Announced" exactly
  const rdaCellCol = tfRaceDateAnnounced.findNext().getColumn()//finds first instance of race date announced
  const rdaCellRow = tfRaceDateAnnounced.findNext().getRow()

  //const/variables to find Training Date Ended
  const tfTrainingDateEnded = ws.createTextFinder('Training Date Ended');
  tfTrainingDateEnded.matchEntireCell(true).matchCase(false);//finds text Training Date Ended
  const tdeCellCol = tfTrainingDateEnded.findNext().getColumn()//finds first instance of training date ended 
  const tdeCellRow = tfTrainingDateEnded.findNext().getRow()

  //const/variables to find Training: Yes or No
  const tfTrain = ws.createTextFinder('Training: Yes or No');
  tfTrain.matchEntireCell(true).matchCase(false);//finds text Training: Yes or No
  const trainCellCol = tfTrain.findNext().getColumn()//finds first instance of Training: Yes or No
  const trainCellRow = tfTrain.findNext().getRow()
  
    //const/variables to find Race Date Commenced 
  const tfRDC = ws.createTextFinder('Race Date Commenced');
  tfRDC.matchEntireCell(true).matchCase(false);//finds text Race Date Commenced
  const rdcCellCol = tfRDC.findNext().getColumn()//finds first instance of race date commenced
  const rdcCellRow = tfRDC.findNext().getRow()



  //variable formulas

  var trainingDaysFormulaNo = [] //is =NETWORKDAYS(Race Date announced, race date commenced) ONLY IF Training is No
  var trainingDaysFormulaYes = [] //is =NETWORKDAYS(race date announced, training date ended) ONLY IF Training is Yes


ws.getRange(regionCellRow+1,regionCellCol,ws.getLastRow(),1).setFormulaR1C1()//not sure if this would work if I can figure out the formula to put in the .setFormulaR1C1 if I could pull the variable formulas and put into this, as an example .setFormulaR1C1(trainingDaysFormulaNo)

}//end of function trainingDays
```

**What I thought my code would do**

I thought this code would allow me to insert the column name range into a R1C1 formula and use the setFormulaR1C1 in the cell range. Also I am not sure what kind of IF statement to do for this function to work properly.

**What I've Tried:**

1. Reviewing some items on stackoverflow but it seems to only relate to changing A1 notation to R1C1 or is excel specific
2. I was hoping to be smart/clever using the text find features to call to the columns and get ranges that way

***References:***

[Using Variables in Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54734143/how-to-use-variable-columns-inside-my-formula-in-google-apps-script)

Comment: It seems to me that you don't need script at all; that is, a single array formula should be able to accomplish this fairly easily. Share a link to your spreadsheet (or a copy of it) with the link's Share permissions set (when creating the link) to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor," so that the volunteer contributors here can test solutions and leave any working approaches for you in the sheet.

Comment: You could be using developer meta data for keeping track of columns.  It will track them even if you change their names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are formulating a script that assumes column headers can be on a different location, I'd recommend using `setFormulas` instead of the R1C1 version since that will have to make use of offsets relative to your header location.

See overhauled script below:

```
function trainingDays(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName('sheet1');

  // search headers (converted to separate function to return row and column)
  const [tfRow, tfCol] = getLocationOfText(ws, 'Training Days');
  const [tfTYNRow, tfTYNCol] = getLocationOfText(ws, 'Training: Yes or No');
  // get columns only for other headers
  const [, tfRDACol] = getLocationOfText(ws, 'Race Date Announced');
  const [, tfRDCCol] = getLocationOfText(ws, 'Race Date Commenced');
  const [, tfTDECol] = getLocationOfText(ws, 'Training Date Ended');
  // convert number to letter for formula substition later 
  const tfRDA = String.fromCharCode(96 + tfRDACol).toUpperCase();
  const tfRDC = String.fromCharCode(96 + tfRDCCol).toUpperCase();
  const tfTDE = String.fromCharCode(96 + tfTDECol).toUpperCase();

  // offset lastRow with row index since data is not starting at 1
  const lastRow = ws.getLastRow();
  const tfTYNVal = ws.getRange(tfTYNRow + 1, tfTYNCol, lastRow - tfTYNRow, 1)
                     .getValues();

  // placeholder for output
  var output = [];

  // generate an array with the formula with each value in Yes/No column
  tfTYNVal.forEach((cell, index) => {
    // get row by offsetting index with row of header (+1 due to 0-indexing)
    var row = (tfTYNRow + index + 1);
    if(cell == 'Yes')
      output.push([`=NETWORKDAYS(${tfRDA}${row}, ${tfTDE}${row},)`]);
    else if(cell == 'No')
      output.push([`=NETWORKDAYS(${tfRDA}${row}, ${tfRDC}${row},)`]);
    // write blank if not yes or no (to avoid setFormulas from breaking)
    else
      output.push(['']);
  });

  // I personally avoided using R1C1 version since that uses offsets on range
  // It will be an issue when header location is changed since it will conform 
  // to the offset given based on your original header location
  ws.getRange(tfRow + 1, tfCol, lastRow - tfRow, 1).setFormulas(output);
}

function getLocationOfText(sheet, text) {
  const tf = sheet.createTextFinder(text);
  tf.matchEntireCell(true).matchCase(false);
  const tfNext = tf.findNext();

  return [tfNext.getRow(), tfNext.getColumn()]
}
```

#### Output 1:

[image: output1]

#### Output 2 (different column locations):

[image: output2]

Comment: thanks @NaziA ! this worked great!

Answer (score 1):

See my comment on your original post.

However, sight-unseen and hence untested, you can try this formula (no script involved) in G1:

`=ArrayFormula({"Training Days"; IF(A2:A="",,NETWORKDAYS(A2:A,IF(F2:F="Yes",D2:D,B2:B)))})`

This single array formula should produce the header and all column results for active rows.

Comment: Oh that's actually a good idea! I would want a script to insert this formula into the sheet though

Comment: I'm not sure what advantage a script would have over a simple formula; in fact, a script represents potential issues (lag, added steps when reproducing or copying/sharing, etc.). A formula will adapt as columns are added or deleted, if that was your concern. As a professional who's been using spreadsheets to create custom solutions from tiny to mammoth since spreadsheets were introduced, I only use script where formulas cannot accomplish something. However, you know more about your project than I do; there may be some reason we "out here" don't know that requires the script over a formula.

Comment: Completely agree and appreciate the input. This is more for ease of use for the end user

Comment: Last I'll say on it. But if you are worried about users accidentally messing with formulas, you can write them to produce the header AND results from Row 1 and then simply protect the formula cell against editing. (Understand that I gain nothing from your using my formula or formulas in general; I'm just trying to share information, both with you and with future site visitors.)